# Navigating a generic list of collection in c#

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection of objects in a generic list.

I am wondering what is the the best way to navigate this collection.
I want to do operations such as "MoveNext", "MovePrevious" etc.

Basically my collection is a number of steps in a flow and I want to be able to move along the steps.

Is there a c# equivalent of MoveNext and MovePrevious in Sql

Comment: what does sql have to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class.
Each element has a reference to the previous and the next one.
Check the link to the documentation for examples.

Comment: The LinkedList<T> object worked. Took me a while to get a system worked out to find the node position based on a search parameter and activate controls accordingly (I'm building a primitive workflow manager on a dynamic form system and I want to be able to "ask" it where is it in the flow so that i can activate some controls, change the form setup and bring the user back to the same point in the chain later). I think this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `Current` property to your list.

not tested. just looks right.

and there is a guard you should implement to your liking, e.g. the starting index. should you start at -1 and require a movenext? up to you

```
   public class BackAndForthList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private int _current = 0;

        public T Current
        {
            get { return this[_current]; }
        }

        public void MoveNext()
        {
            _current++;
            if (_current >= Count)

            {
                _current = 0;
            }
        }

        public void MovePrevious()
        {
            _current--;

            if (_current < 0)
            {
                _current = Count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That might work nicely too. Why can't I mark two answers in stackoverflow ;)  Oh well, thanks, have a vote at least!

Answer (score 1):

For moving forward you could use an Enumerator:

```
list.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of built in functionality to do this, but you can do this very simply by having a variable holding the index.  When you want MoveNext then i++ and when you want MovePrevious use i-- (That is assuming you use i as the variable).

EDIT:  I was wrong.  Here is a snippet from MSDN that does just what you ask. I haven't looked deeply into it, but it was in the article about [StringCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx)

```
public static void PrintValues2( StringCollection myCol )  {
      StringEnumerator myEnumerator = myCol.GetEnumerator();
      while ( myEnumerator.MoveNext() )
         Console.WriteLine( "   {0}", myEnumerator.Current );
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BindingList` or `BindingSource` or derive your own from either.